# SATA-to-USB adapter turns off HDMI output

Tags: usb, display, usb3

When plugging in an SSD via SATA-to-USB adapter, it turns off HDMI output but I can still SSH into the pi. What is the issue?

```
Model: Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB
OS: Debian Bullseye aarch64
Kernel: 5.10.83-v8+
```

Comment: what happens if an SSD is not connected to the adapter?

Comment: You don't give us much information. Is there anything in the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it was a faulty power adapter for the Pi. I used an official Raspberry power supply and the issue has been fixed.